# Validação javascript não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html, validação

estou preso num problema. Fiz um formulário html e criei um documento javascript, porém a função que criei não funcio (como se nem estivesse senfo chamada) já tentei várias coias e ainda não consegui.

Eis aqui os códigos:

```js
function validar(){

 var d = document.formulario;
 
 if(d.nome.value==""){

  alert("Campo em branco");
  return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Aula Prática</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formularioScript.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="formulario">
   <div>
    ID: <input type:"text" id="formId" placeholder="Digite sua ID">
    <br></br>
   </div>

   <div>
    Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
    <br></br>
   </div>

   <div>
    CPF: <input type="text" id="formCpf" placeholder="Digite deu CPF">
    <br></br>
   </div>
   
   <div>
    Data: <input type="date" id="formData">
    <br></br>
   </div>

   <div>
    Gênero: <input type="integer" id="formGen">
    <br></br>
   </div>

   <div>
    Ano: <input type="integer" id="formAno">
    <br></br>
   </div>

   <div>
    Semestre: <input type="integer" id="formSem">
    <br></br>
   </div>

   <div>
    Número de Disciplinas: <input type="integer" id="formDisci">
    <br></br>
   </div>

   <div>
    Email: <input type="text" id="formEmail">
    <br></br>
   </div>

   <div>
    Cor Administrador: <input type="text" id="formCor">
    <br></br>  
   </div>

   <input type="button" id="validar" value="Confirmar" onclick="validar()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função não está a ser chamada pois existe um [conflito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id) entre o id do botão (`validar`) e o nome da função, que é também `validar`:

Troque o id do botão para outra coisa.

Ajustei a parte de javascript consoante o que me parece que quer:

```js
function validar(){
  inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var missing = 'Falta: ';
  for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
      if(inputs[index].value == '') {
    missing += inputs[index].id+ ', ';
      }
  }
  if(missing !== 'Falta: ') {
      alert(missing);
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">

    ID: <input type="text" id="formId" placeholder="Digite sua ID">
    <br>


    Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
    <br>


    CPF: <input type="text" id="formCpf" placeholder="Digite deu CPF">
    <br>
   
    Data: <input type="date" id="formData">
    <br>


    Gênero: <input type="integer" id="formGen">
    <br>


    Ano: <input type="integer" id="formAno">
    <br>

   <div>
    Semestre: <input type="integer" id="formSem">
    <br>


    Número de Disciplinas: <input type="integer" id="formDisci">
    <br>


    Email: <input type="text" id="formEmail">
    <br>


    Cor Administrador: <input type="text" id="formCor">
    <br>

   <input type="button" id="validar_id" value="Confirmar" onclick="validar();return false;">
   </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção! Fiz as alterações e continua não validando, até refiz esse seu código no meu e mesmo assim não vai. Verifiquei se não é problema na chamada do doc js pelo doc html mas está tudo ok aparentemente. :/

Comment: Se quiser pode http://www.filedropper.com/ , e enviar-te o link de download que eu dou uma olhadela

Comment: Você chegou a mudar o nome do id do botão?

Comment: Mudei sim. Tanto o ID quanto a questão do "name".

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu consegui! Conforme você e os outros me orientaram fui fazendo as alterações e concertando os erros mas mesmo assim não era ativado o alert() (com o script dentro do html ou num doc a parte). Consegui imprimir só com o script no html aí identifiquei que o que estava ocasionando o erro foi esse trecho: src="js/formularioScript.js". Só precisei tirar o "js/". Mais uma vez agradeço por toda a ajuda!

Comment: Ok, ainda bem, pode aceitar a resposta que mais o ajudou a resolver

Answer (score 0):

Sempre quando for se referir em javascript diretamente a campos, colocar o atributo name ="nome", pois colocando somente o atributo id ele não localizará o objeto diretamente, como usando document.formulario.nome

Ou simplesmente use:

```
  if(document.getElementById("nome").value=="")
       return alert("Campo em branco") && false;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção! Fiz as alterações e continua não validando, até refiz esse seu código no meu e mesmo assim não vai. Verifiquei se não é problema na chamada do doc js pelo doc html mas está tudo ok aparentemente. :/

Comment: Chegou a funcionar em https://jsfiddle.net/b9m6ajvb/
Mas também foi necessário mudar o nome do controle ou da função para um diferente

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu consegui! Conforme você e os outros me orientaram fui fazendo as alterações e concertando os erros mas mesmo assim não era ativado o alert() (com o script dentro do html ou num doc a parte). Consegui imprimir só com o script no html aí identifiquei que o que estava ocasionando o erro foi esse trecho: src="js/formularioScript.js". Só precisei tirar o "js/". Mais uma vez agradeço por toda a ajuda!